# MVC pass POSTed data to a View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, http-post

My Index View displays a table of members loaded from it's `Index()` action method. Each table row has a checkbox. Outside the table is a Remove button.

The Remove button (when clicked) sends a `POST` request containing the `ViewModel` data (i.e. rows IDs) to it's `POST` action method `Index()`.

All pretty standard so far. Until the next part (which I'm not happy about)...

In the `Index()` post action method, I store the rows IDs to `TempData` and then `RedirectToAction` to the `Remove() GET` action method.
I would like to commit the data to the database here, but I have to display a "Are you sure you want to delete these records" page. Hence the redirect.

In the `Remove() GET` action method, I fetch the row data from `TempData`, then display the rows (using their `ID`s I fetch data from the database). Clicking the Submit button sends a `POST` request and the `Remove() POST` action method deletes these rows.

Using the `TempData` between both these `GET/POST` request 'pairs' looks like a path, i.e. poor design to get it to work. Given the data is a collection, `List<int>()`, i.e. a complex type, I can't use `RedirectToAction` here.

**Question**: Is there a better way to pass the `POST`ed data (selected rows) to be displayed to a `View`?

There are a number of SO posts asking whether a `RedirectToAction` via `POST` is possible, and the answer seems to 'No'. Which is understandable.

**An Option**: If there's no other approach, then I might have to consider using a Bootstrap Modal with the selected row data displayed, and a Remove button which `POST`s via Ajax. But the problem with this is trying to read a list of selected (checkbox checked) rows from a `View` via jQuery appears difficult (for me with some working jQuery knowledge). Then `POST`ing via Ajax.

Code snippets below, I've removed unrelated code so ignore any syntax/spelling mistakes.

Index View

```
@model MyProject.Models.Members.MembersViewModel

... more view code

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Members", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            ... table with @EditorFor()

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Remove" id="buttonRemove" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Controller Index() action methods

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MembersViewModel membersViewModel = new MembersViewModel();

    // Fetch members from the database
    List<Member> members = _BLL.GetAllMembers();

    // Map domain model to viewmodel
... automapper code here
    membersViewModel.Members = members;
    return View(membersViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(MembersViewModel membersViewModel)
{
    // Get the ids of the items selected (GetSelectedIDs() method on VM iterates through private list and returns selected IDs)
    IEnumerable<int> selectedMembersIDs = membersViewModel.GetSelectedIDs();

    // Store IDs
    TempData["SelectedMembers"] = selectedMembersIDs.ToList();
    return RedirectToAction("Remove");
}
```

---

Controller Remove() action methods

```
public ActionResult Remove()
{
    List<int> selectedMembersIDs = TempData["SelectedMembers"] as List<int>;
    if (selectedMembersIDs.Count == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // Fetch members details
    List<Member> members = _BLL.GetSelectedMembers(selectedMembersIDs);
    if (members.Count == 0)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // Map domain model to viewmodel
    DeleteMembersViewModel deleteMembersViewModel = new DeleteMembersViewModel();
    foreach (Member member in members)
    {
        deleteMembersViewModel.Members.Add(member);
    }            
    return View(deleteMembersViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Remove(DeleteMembersViewModel deleteMembersViewModel)
{
    List<int> selectedMembersIDs = new List<int>();
    foreach(Member member in deleteMembersViewModel.Members)
    {
        selectedMembersIDs.Add(member.ID);
    }

    _BLL.RemoveGroupMembers(selectedMembersIDs);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: All i see is wall of text. You are describing your code, it would be easier for everyone if you could just post the relevant bits of code.

Comment: can u post the code please ??

Comment: fot this kind of situation like confirm messages,using client side seems more conventional and user-friendly

Comment: Added code... sorry about that.